# Trouble with encondig in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the next table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `applications` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I want to store the value "España" in the "name" field.

I have a PHP FILE (encoded in UTF8) with a form to save that. When i save "España" using the php file and i read from mysql with php i see the data ok.

But if a go to PMA o Mysql Query Browser i see this: "EspaÃ±a"

If i save it from PMA (with encoding set to UTF-8 ) or mysql query browser i see ok on that two tools, but i see "Espa�a" from PHP.

I dont understand why.

In bytes:

If is saved from PHP i see:  C3 83 C2 B1 (for ñ)

If is saved from MQB or PMA i see: C3 B1 (for ñ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the php mysql client. It uses latin1 as encoding for the connection, you can see this with:

```
echo mysql_client_encoding($con);
```

or

```
print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("show variables like 'char%';")));
```

There is two ways to solve this:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

or

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'", $con); // data send by the server
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'", $con); // data send by the client
```

Answer (score 0):

Run [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) before executing queries on the open connection.

```
mysql_set_charset("UTF-8");
```